# C# - Why is my HTTPWebRequest returning a cached response every time?

Tags: c#, caching, httpwebrequest

I've seen various similar questions to this, but nothing has helped solve my issue.  Here's a code fragment with which I'm working:

```
NetworkCredential credentials = new NetworkCredential(CredentialsManager.Username, CredentialsManager.Password);

HttpWebRequest getReq = (HttpWebRequest) WebRequest.Create(m_editPageUrl);
getReq.CachePolicy = new RequestCachePolicy(RequestCacheLevel.BypassCache); // I've also tried RequestCacheLevel.NoCacheNoStore
getReq.Credentials = credentials;
getReq.Timeout = 1000;
getReq.Method = "GET";
getReq.Accept = "text/html";

string responseString;
using (HttpWebResponse getResponse = (HttpWebResponse) getReq.GetResponse())
{
    using (Stream responseStream = getResponse.GetResponseStream())
    {
        if (responseStream == null)
            throw new Exception("Did not receive a response from the specified page.");

        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(responseStream))
            responseString = reader.ReadToEnd();
    }
}
```

For some reason, whatever gets stored into responseString is being cached, even though I've told the HTTPWebRequest to bypass the cache.  About every hour, I get a newer response, but then if I change anything, the newer response (which should now be invalidated since there's an even newer version) is still passed to me.  I've been told on good authority that the server is set up to not cache responses, so I must be doing something wrong.  I just can't figure out what.

I read somewhere that it may help to make a more low-level loader using sockets.  However, I couldn't find anywhere that easily showed how to do this.  If this is what I should do, please let me know where to look to find help on that.

Thanks.

Comment: I would try testing using a proxy tool (like http://fiddler2.com/).  This will tell you if it is the client or the server doing the caching.

Comment: Actually, I have that exact program running right now.  When I send the request, the headers indicate that caching should be disabled (Content-Control: no-cache, Pragma: no-cache).  However, the response I get is an old one.  It seems to me like this means that the server is passing things back incorrectly.  However, I've been assured that it's working correctly.  Do you think it's a server-side or client-side issue?

Comment: @BrianGradin: If the server is sending wrong data, it almost definitely isn't a client-side issue.

Comment: @BrianGradin - There are web servers that don't support various caching scenarios. If this is something outside of your control then you have no choice but to handle it in your code (and deal with any side effects).

Comment: I know this is very basic, but have you tried adding random number to your request URL as a param?

Comment: Haha.  Hacky to the max.  Yes, I tried this, and it didn't work.  At this point, I'm pretty sure that there's a server-side issue, but I'd like to be completely sure I've tried everything I can from my side.  I'm not going to push for a server-side fix until the request has the correct caching in fiddler.

Comment: Instead of messing with the C# code, first use the "Request Builder" function in Fiddler to manually set the request headers the way you want.  Then you can test the server without worrying about the client.  Also check to make sure that the "Rules > Performance > Disable Caching" menu item is disabled in Fiddler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While doing some digging in the code for the site hosted on the server my application accesses, I found out that the site has a cache service which it maintains. Once this was disabled, everything ran like a charm. My original code works fine.